# std::vector constructor taking pair of iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I am making some sort of container and I would like to mimic the interface of an [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). However, I am having a hard time understanding how [the constructor overload (4)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) works. The problem is that it normally conflicts with overload (2).

```
// (2)
vector(size_type count, const T& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
// (4)
template<class InputIt>
vector(InputIt first, InputIt last, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

According to cppreference, until C++11 :

> this constructor has the same effect as overload (2) if InputIt is an integral type.

I understand how it was done (tag dispatching or template specialization, I suppose), but I have no idea how the new behavior is achieved in C++11 :

> This overload only participates in overload resolution if InputIt satisfies [InputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator), to avoid ambiguity with the overload (2).

Is that some sort of SFINAE trick ? I do not understand how SFINAE could work here. And, since concepts or not a thing in C++11 (nor C++14), I have no idea about how I could do that for my container.

Hence my question : how is it done in the standard library (or at least a guess), and how can I do it relatively easily for my container ?

Comment: Pedantic remark: There is not *the* standard library implementation. libc++'s vector implementation [uses SFINAE via `enable_if`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/vector#L532). libstdc++ [uses a similar implementation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01523_source.html#l00401), but leaves out the constructibility check.

Comment: @dyp Yes, I know there is not a unique implementation, but I didn't know how to formulate it (that's why I added "or at least a guess"). Thanks for the links, that's interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way it's currently worded in the standard is rather interesting. [sequence.reqmts]/p15:

> The extent to which an implementation determines that a type cannot be
>   an input iterator is unspecified, except that as a minimum integral
>   types shall not qualify as input iterators.

In other words, it's sufficient for implementations to test for integral types only, but they can do more if they want to.

With a SFINAE-friendly `std::iterator_traits` (voted into the C++17 working paper as an LWG issue, but probably provided by most implementations all along anyway), for example, one might test that `std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::iterator_category` is valid and denotes a type derived from `std::input_iterator_tag` with something like

```
template<class InputIt, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<std::input_iterator_tag,
                            typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::iterator_category>::value, int> = 0>
vector(InputIt first, InputIt last, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

Note that this is just a proof-of-concept. Real implementations in standard libraries would probably be 1) more complex (for example, it may optimize based on iterator category - for forward iterators or better, it can allocate memory for all the elements in one go) and 2) even uglier than this and filled with underscores to avoid name conflicts.